# Can I Populate / update a new record after using find_or_initialize_by with one line like when using new()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modalviewcontroller, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am in the process of changing some functionality and as such, I want to use `find_or_initialize_by` to replace `new`

My modal has 13 columns

```
modal = Modal.new(col1: col1, col2: col2..... col13: col13)
```

The new code is:

```
modal = Modal.find_or_initialize_by(col1: col1, col3: col3)
```

and now I need to either populate or update the remaining 11 columns.

Can this be done on one line? I would rather not write:

```
modal.col1 = col1
modal.col2 = col2
....
modal.col13 = col13
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a block to set the attributes to the new records. This is useful when you want to create them with some values and you don't want to override the existing records.

```
modal = Modal.find_or_initialize_by(col1: col1, col3: col3) do |record|
  record.col4 = col4
  record.col5 = col5
  # etc
end
```

You can play with its syntax to oneline it, using `#attributes=`:

```
modal = Modal.find_or_initialize_by(col1: col1, col3: col3) { |r| r.attributes = { col4: col4, col5: col5 } }
```

Note that `#attributes=` will only set the values, you have to manually save. If you use `.find_or_create_by` instead of  `.find_or_initialize_by`, it will validate and save the new record after the block's execution.

If you want to set the attributes the record, regardless if it's new or not:

```
modal = Modal.find_or_initialize_by(col1: col1, col3: col3)
modal.attributes = { col4: col4, col5: col5 }
```

You can also use `#update_attributes`, but your record will be validated and saved.

```
modal = Modal.find_or_initialize_by(col1: col1, col3: col3)
modal.update_attributes(col4: col4, col5: col5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that looks much nicer!

Comment: I've had to unselect this as an answer. The block is only called when a new record is created, so it will not update an existing one.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that you needed to set the attributes for all the records, new or existing. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, that's great!